# Why is this element not interactable? Python (Selenium)

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm really struggling to understand why this element is not interactable.

I have tried locating it by span text, by class name, using ActionChains... nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Python:

```
menu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='OK']").click();
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(menu)
actions.click(menu)
actions.perform()
```

[image: )]

[image]

Comment: What error you are getting when you run your script?

Answer (score 0):

The element is not interactable because it is a `span` -- typically, `span` elements are not meant to accept clicks, they are just meant to contain and display text. You might have better luck trying Javascript, or trying to locate the element one level above the span. I would also invoke `WebDriverWait` on the button to ensure it is properly loaded before attempting to interact with it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# invoke WebDriverWait to locate the div element that is one level above the span
menu = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[span[text()='OK']]")))

# click the menu
menu.click()
```